# Numpy masked array argmax not returning 'masked' on fully masked array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a masked array in numpy.ma, for which all values are masked:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
arr = ma.array([3,4,10], mask=[True, True, True])
```

I expect that operations on this array, such as `ma.sum` should return `masked`:

```
>>> ma.sum(arr) is ma.masked
>>> True
```

And this is indeed `True`.

But when I use `ma.argmax()` on the same array, the result is not `ma.masked` but rather `0`

```
>>> ma.argmax(arr) is ma.masked
>>> False
>>> ma.argmax(arr)
>>> 0
```

Any ideas? is this a bug, or expected behavior? Ideally, this would return `masked`. Can anyone think of a good workaround, or am I being silly... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> arr[ma.argmax(arr)]
masked
```

`argmax` returns the *index* of the maximum value. You can use the index to get the value. The *value* is masked.

Because all the values are masked, they are considered equal (to the `fill_value`), and `argmax` returns the first index as documented (in [the docs of `numpy.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)).

Answer (score 2):

`np.argmax` returns a scalar so it doesn't make sense for it to return a masked array.

From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.argmax.html) (emphasis mine):

> Returns array of indices of the maximum values along the given axis.
>   **Masked values are treated as if they had the value fill_value**.